# Why did NPM stopped working after an update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

2 Days ago I Updated NPM and yesterday I realized that it stopped working.

My platform is Windows 10 20H2.

Every single thing I do gives me the same error.

```
C:\Users\ethan>npm
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'code-point-at'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\string-width\index.js
- C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\wide-truncate.js
- C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\render-template.js
- C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\plumbing.js
- C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\index.js
- C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\log.js
- C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\string-width\index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\ethan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\node_modules\\string-width\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ethan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\wide-truncate.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ethan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\render-template.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ethan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\plumbing.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ethan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ethan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npmlog\\log.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ethan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ethan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

I've already tried reinstalling node and NPM but it didn't worked.

What should I do and why did this happened?
Please help me with this, Thanks.

Comment: What version of NPM were you using previously, what version are you using now? Did you try to install different major versions of npm?

Comment: @JSONDerulo I Think I was using 7.6.0 and that happened when I updated it at 7.6.1, I like to have NPM always updated, I'd Downgrade but I can't without npm.

Comment: Did you try installing specificly version 7.6.0, or another specific version? (`npm i -g npm@7.6.0`)

Comment: @JSONDerulo I don't know how to install other versions of NPM wihtout NPM, I will usually write ```npm install npm@7.6.0 -g``` but it doesnt work.

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache? Although *if everything is working properly* the cache shouldn't cause any errors, you can force it to clear with npm-cache clear --force - you need --force because npm believes it can't have a dodgy cache.

Comment: @speciesUnknown Any npm command doesn't work.

Comment: @TheSpeddyEthanYT even npm-cache? its a different command (although it is an alias) - what about npm --version

Comment: @speciesUnknown no, it gives me the same error.

Comment: From a bit of googling, that particular module has lots of issues like this - rebooting, or reinstalling, seems to help some people.

Comment: @speciesUnknown Still, I reinstalled and rebooted and still.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its me, I Finished using Ubuntu WSL for getting the attachment link of the missing dependencies, Thank you for your help @JSON Derulo @speciesUnknown.